# When to use the `#` symbol to get a DOM element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementbyid

Sometimes I need to get elements like this:

```
var object = document.getElementById('ObjectName');
```

And sometimes like this:

```
var object = document.getElementById('#ObjectName');
```

What’s the difference between them?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjs%5d%20getelementbyid%20code:"%23"): [Why does `document.getElementById("#datepicker1")` not find my element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33036800/4642212), [Why am I getting “Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null at ahint”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54554975/4642212), [Why does `document.getElementById("#sideNav")` not find my element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38479889/4642212), [\[1\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62478560/4642212), [\[2\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17303764/4642212), and probably a few more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you don't see

```
var object = document.getElementById('#ObjectName');
```

You don't see that because that would mean the id of the element starts with `#` and HTML4 id could only start ["with a letter ([A-Za-z])"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id).

What you see is sometimes people using the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library in which the query language allows you to find an object using

```
var elem = $('#objectId');
```

And in the future you'll see more and more people using a similar query language with [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelector) or [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.querySelectorAll).

Comment: But `id` attributes starting with `#` are fair game in HTML5, so the questioner technically *could* have seen that code.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi "I always used it" lets me think OP isn't dealing with code gaining from the last versions of HTML.

Comment: This answer is a bit out of date (HTML5 allows `#` at the beginning, even though it’s recommended to start with a letter, and it is the future now). The other answers are more up to date. At least fix the unmatching parenthesis.

Answer (score 7):

The `#` is part of the [ID selector in CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#id-selectors). There are libraries and methods which support CSS selectors for selecting elements, such as jQuery and the native DOM methods [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelector) and [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll).

But in "traditional" DOM method, the `#` has no special meaning. `getElementById('#ObjectName')` would select an element which *literally* has the ID `#ObjectName`, i.e. `<div id="#ObjectName">`.

Answer (score 6):

The former gets an element with `id="ObjectName"`.
The latter gets an element with `id="#ObjectName"`.

In the context of a [Selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/) (as used, for example, by CSS and `document.querySelector` but not with `getElementById`) the `#` character indicates that the text following it is an id.

`document.querySelector('ObjectName')` (using a type selector) would get `<ObjectName />` (not valid HTML) while `document.querySelector('#ObjectName')` would get an element with `id="ObjectName"`.

Answer (score -1):

```
'#ObjectName'
```

JQuery (**EDIT:** or other JavaScript Libraries)

```
'ObjectName'
```

DOM (getElementById)

Comment: Selector syntax is used in many more places then that JS library.

Comment: You are diffidently right, i'm just used to it so it was first thing in mind when thinking about JS Libraries.