# Why does `document.getElementById(“#datepicker1”)` not find my element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementbyid

I am trying to show / hide a text input based on the selection of a drop down list.

Here’s a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SimonPrice/1a5Ljevm/1/) to what I am trying to do.

When I get into the function, I get a *“`TypeError`: Cannot set property '`type`' of `null`”*.

This is the code:

```
function showCustomDate(val) {
  console.log(val);
  if (val == 4) {
    var y = document.getElementById("#datepicker1");
    
    //console.log(y.type);
    y.type = "text";
  }
  else {
    var y = document.getElementById("#datepicker1");
    
    //console.log(y.type);
    y.type = "hidden";
  }
};
```

Comment: can someone explain how this if off topic?

Comment: Related: [When to use the `#` symbol to get a DOM element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15486154/4642212).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`y` is null, because the id of the element is probably `datepicker1` and not `#datepicker1`

```
var y = document.getElementById("#datepicker1");
```

should be

```
var y = document.getElementById("datepicker1");
```

Answer (score 4):

You do not need the `#` when using `getElementById`. `getElementById` returns `null` if does not find the element. `null` does not have a `property` named `type` - therefore you get the error.

```
function showCustomDate(val) {
   console.log(val);
   if (val == 4) {
      var y = document.getElementById("datepicker1"); //removed #
      //console.log(y.type);
      y.type = "text";
   } else {
       var y = document.getElementById("datepicker1"); //removed #
       //console.log(y.type);
       y.type = "hidden";
   }
};
```