# Why does `document.getElementById("#sideNav")` not find my element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementbyid

Why is this code throwing *“`TypeError`: Cannot read property '`style`' of `null`”*?

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("#sideNav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("#sideNav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```html
<div class="sidenav" id="sideNav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closenav" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Listing</a>
  <a href="#">About Us</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
<span onclick="openNav()">OPEN</span>
<div id="main">
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does \`document.getElementById(“#datepicker1”)\` not find my element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33036800/why-does-document-getelementbyid-datepicker1-not-find-my-element)

Comment: Related: [When to use the `#` symbol to get a DOM element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15486154/4642212).

Answer (score 8):

Because `getElementById` takes an **id**, not a CSS selector. Just lose the `#` on those:

```
document.getElementById("sideNav").style.width = "250px";
// No # here ------------^
```

`querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` take CSS selectors, but `getElementById` does exactly what the name suggests: Gets an element by its ID.