# Why am I getting "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null at ahint"

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I have tried to write some code in JS but, when I hover my mouse, the error "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null at ahint" is seen. I have read that such an error can occur because Chrome compiles/renders the JS code before the Div is even created. Therefore, I have put it on the bottom to check it. Unfortunately, putting it on the bottom has not solved my problem. Maybe someone more experienced will understand it.

```js
var hint = "Hello";

function ahint()
{
    document.getElementById('#randomhint').innerHTML = hint;
}
```

```html
    <div id="randomhint" onmouseover="ahint()">!</div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I have edited your answer for idiom. However, to what the pronoun *it* refers in "I have put **it** on the bottom" remains unclear to me. You might edit that.

Comment: If you read the docs for `getElementById` you'll see your mistake.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does \`document.getElementById(“#datepicker1”)\` not find my element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33036800/why-does-document-getelementbyid-datepicker1-not-find-my-element)

Comment: Related: [When to use # symbol to get object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15486154/4642212).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `#` from the identifier:

```
var hint = "Hello";

function ahint()
{
    document.getElementById('randomhint').innerHTML = hint;
}
```

You have likely seen the `#` in code that uses jQuery or a similar library, as in `$('#randomhint')`. That’s how those libraries know that you mean to use an `id` and not, say, a tag name.

But you do not need (and cannot use) it when using `getElementById` (which is part of “vanilla” JavaScript). With `getElementById`, only the actual `id` value (`"randomhint"`) belongs there.

Comment: Thanks, can you maybe explain why the caused the problem?

Comment: Edge case for a _typo_ question, still, also _vanilla_ javascript can use `#id`, e.g. `querySelector`

Comment: @LGSon It is, of course, a kind of typo. But some typo questions are valid when they are about the logic and syntax of the language, as opposed to pure errors like `getEEElementById`. And I didn’t mean to imply that vanilla JavaScript never uses `#` in this way; I’ve edited my answer to clarify.

Comment: Great..and understood that, hence I wrote _edge case_ :)