# 'addEventListener' not working on Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I added an addEventListener to my window, but it is returning the following errors:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'addEventListener' on 'EventTarget': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present. at

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', setUpStuff, false);
```

Another error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null (at:

```
 optionsButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
```

Here is the code:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', setUpStuff, false);
function setUpStuff(){
    let optionsButton = document.getElementById('#go-to-options');
    optionsButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage) {
          chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage();
        } else {
          window.open(chrome.runtime.getURL('options.html'));
        }
      });
}
```

Comment: `optionsButton.addEventListener(function()` - you're missing the event type you want to listen to. `"click"` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does \`document.getElementById(“#datepicker1”)\` not find my element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33036800/why-does-document-getelementbyid-datepicker1-not-find-my-element)

Comment: Related: [When to use the `#` symbol to get a DOM element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15486154/4642212).

Answer (score 2):

You are supposed to add an event on the execution of which the function is going to be run. And `getElementById` takes an ID, not a selector, so you need to remove the `#`:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', setUpStuff, false);
function setUpStuff(){
    let optionsButton = document.getElementById('go-to-options');
    optionsButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage) {
          chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage();
        } else {
          window.open(chrome.runtime.getURL('options.html'));
        }
      });
}
```

Comment: I added your code, but I am getting another error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null on "optionsButton.addEventListener('click', function() {"

Comment: remove the id sign from this code  let optionsButton = document.getElementById('#go-to-options');  Should be like this  let optionsButton = document.getElementById('go-to-options'); You are already telling to select an id, you don't need the id sign.

Comment: Awesome! I got the right answer. Thank you so much!