# Why is this simple JavaScript stopwatch not working?

Tags: javascript, chronometer

I wrote some very simple code the should represent a stopwatch with two buttons where clicking 'Start' should start counting upwards from 0 with 1 second delay.

However, when I click nothing changes. Where is my mistake?

```js
"use strict";
var s = 1;

function mf() {
  setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("#sw").innerText = ++s;
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<div id="sw">0</div>
<input type="button" value="Start" name="start" onlick="mf" />
<input type="button" value="Stop" name="stop" />
```

Comment: Don't use the hash in getElementById, it's not jQuery

Comment: You need to call your function onclick. `onclick="mf"` should be `onclick="mf()"`.

Comment: And it's not onlick, it's onclick. On lick is something else :)

Comment: `onlick` might be a nice addition for some future devices. We can only imagine ;-)

Comment: I added a working example to my answer- please accept it if it helped

Comment: @Zack105 thanks a lot friend, how must i accept it?

Comment: @ECoder- Under my answer score (between the up and down arrows, to the left of my answer), there should be a checkmark. Just click it, and that's it! Thanks!

Comment: @Zack105 your wellcome, i did it.

Comment: Related: [When to use the `#` symbol to get a DOM element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15486154/4642212).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two issues:

**1):** You're using

```
onlick="mf"
```

However, it should be:

```
onclick="mf();"
```

**2):**  You used a `#` in your 'getElementByID'. This isn't jQuery- use

```
document.getElementById("sw")
```

**Working Answer**

```js
"use strict";
 var s = 1;

  function mf() {
  setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("sw").innerText = s++;
   }, 1000);
 }
```

```html
<div id="sw">0</div>
<input type="button" value="Start" name="start" onclick="mf();" />
<input type="button" value="Stop" name="stop" />
```

Your errors:

```
    document.getElementById("#sw").innerText = ++s;
```

should be

```
    document.getElementById("sw").innerText = s++;
```

Remove the `#`, and use `s++`, not `++s`.

```
 <input type="button" value="Start" name="start" onlick="mf" />
```

That code has 2 errors: `onlick` and `mf`. `Onlick` isn't supported by all browsers yet (xD). Use `onclick` instead. Also, include the parameters, so `mf()`

Comment: `onclick` not `onlick`

Comment: @nem035- thanks, I just copied what the OA used. I didn't check for that

Comment: thank you now works very good. :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have a typo. You typed `onlick` instead of `onclick`. Second, `document.getElementById` takes a string that refers to the id of the element you are trying to get. However, it does not need a #.

```
document.getElementById("sw")
```

Comment: oh yes, thank you it solved.